# Binary variable in Gurobi solver

Tags: julia, gurobi

I run my code in Julia language, using a notebook, and a Gurobi solver. The problem is I have a defined binary variable, but the Gurobi solver provides me with a numerical value. For example, the results should provide the optimal number of buses in the system, but the result is **7.999**?

Comment: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012237872-Why-does-Gurobi-sometimes-return-values-for-integer-variables-that-are-not-integers-

Answer (score 2):

This is how integer programming works; please see the Gurobi knowledge base article [Why does Gurobi sometimes return values for integer variables that are not integers?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012237872-Why-does-Gurobi-sometimes-return-values-for-integer-variables-that-are-not-integers-)